# Playing a sound when an error occurs in a macro

Tags: excel, debugging, audio, alert

is it possible to play a sound when a (scheduled) macro causes an error? (excel vba)
I found the following

The .sound_notify command causes a sound to be played when WinDbg enters the wait-for-command state.
.sound_notify /ed 
.sound_notify /ef File 
.sound_notify /d

but don't know  how where to manage

thanks

Comment: What does it mean "scheduled macro go in debug"?

Comment: I think what he is trying to say is if there is an error make a sound.

Comment: correct, if there is an error, make a sound, because I work with API's  and sometimes it can  happen a value not come (correct)